# Ошибка при установке MS SQL Server 2019 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

Во время установки выскакивает окно:
[image: Ошибка]

Или такое, если устанавливать в базовом режиме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Журнал:

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  Ошибка:
> дополнительные сведения см. ниже   Exit code (Decimal):
> -2061893606   Start time:                    2022-01-12 20:10:00   End time:                      2022-01-12 20:15:40   Requested action:
> Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
> information for those features:   Next step for FullText:
> Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент,
> а затем запустите установку еще раз.   Next step for SQLEngine:
> Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент,
> а затем запустите установку еще раз.   Next step for Replication:
> Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент,
> а затем запустите установку еще раз.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  DESKTOP-NJDBJCL
> Machine processor count:       8   OS version:
> Майкрософт Windows 11 Домашняя (10.0.22000)   OS service pack:
> OS region:                     Россия   OS language:
> русский (Россия)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
> architecture:          64-разрядная версия   OS clustered:
> Нет
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
> Instance ID                    Feature
> Language             Edition              Version         Clustered
> Configured
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
> Server 2019    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019   Type:
> RTM   Version:                       15   SPLevel:
> 0   Installation location:
> D:\SQL2019\ExpressAdv_RUS\x64\setup\   Installation edition:
> Express
>
> Product Update Status:   Не обнаружено.
>
> Параметры пользовательского ввода:   ACTION:
> Install   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
> NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
> AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled   ASBACKUPDIR:
> Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
> ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
> Data   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:
> 1   ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR   ASSVCACCOUNT:
> <пусто>   ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>   ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <пусто>   ASTELSVCACCT:
> <пусто>   ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
> ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
> BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CLTCTLRNAME:
> <пусто>   CLTRESULTDIR:                  <пусто>   CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
> 0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <пусто>   CLTSVCPASSWORD:
> <пусто>   CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <пусто>
> COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
> COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
> CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:
> <пусто>   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <пусто>   CTLRUSERS:
> <пусто>   ENABLERANU:                    true   ENU:
> false   EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <пусто>   EXTSVCPASSWORD:
> <пусто>   FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION,
> FULLTEXT, CONN, BC, SDK, SNAC_SDK   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
> FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <пусто>   FTSVCACCOUNT:
> NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher   FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>
> HELP:                          false   IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:
> false   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
> IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false   INDICATEPROGRESS:
> false   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <пусто>
> INSTANCEDIR:                   D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
> INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER   INSTANCENAME:
> MSSQLSERVER   ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network
> Service   ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <пусто>   ISMASTERSVCPORT:
> 8391   ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <пусто>
> ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic   ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:
> <пусто>   ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
> ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   ISTELSVCACCT:                  <пусто>   ISTELSVCPASSWORD:
> <пусто>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:
> NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <пусто>
> ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <пусто>   ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:
> <пусто>   ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
> MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:
> <пусто>   MATRIXNAME:                    <пусто>   MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
> NPENABLED:                     0   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:
> <пусто>   PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
> PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:
> <пусто>   PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <пусто>
> PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBPORTRANGE:
> <пусто>   PBSCALEOUT:                    false   PID:
> *****   QUIET:                         false   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
> RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:
> <пусто>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <пусто>   RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   SAPWD:                         <пусто>   SECURITYMODE:
> <пусто>   SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <пусто>   SQLCOLLATION:
> Cyrillic_General_CI_AS   SQLJAVADIR:                    <пусто>
> SQLMAXDOP:                     0   SQLMAXMEMORY:
> 2147483647   SQLMINMEMORY:                  0   SQLSVCACCOUNT:
> NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
> SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           DESKTOP-NJDBJCL\Konnv
> SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
> SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <пусто>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
> Automatic   SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <пусто>
> SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
> SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
> <пусто>   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:
> 8   SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <пусто>   SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
> <пусто>   SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
> SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   TCPENABLED:
> 0   UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance   UpdateEnabled:
> true   UpdateSource:                  MU   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:
> false   USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false   X86:
> false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220112_200922\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Полнотекстовый и
> семантический поиск   Status:                        Сбой   Reason for
> failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из зависимостей
> компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.   Next Step:
> Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент,
> а затем запустите установку еще раз.   Component name:
> Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server   Component error code:
> 0x851A001A   Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании
> дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале
> ошибок SQL Server.   Error help link:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026
>
> Feature:                       Службы ядра СУБД   Status:
> Сбой   Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка при установке
> компонента.   Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку,
> пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите
> установку еще раз.   Component name:                Экземпляры служб
> ядра СУБД SQL Server   Component error code:          0x851A001A
> Error description:             Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора
> восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL
> Server.   Error help link:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026
>
> Feature:                       Репликация SQL Server   Status:
> Сбой   Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка для одной из
> зависимостей компонента, вызвавшая сбой процесса его установки.   Next
> Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими
> сведениями, удалите компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
> Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
> Component error code:          0x851A001A   Error description:
> Ошибка при ожидании дескриптора восстановления ядра СУБД. Возможные
> причины см. в журнале ошибок SQL Server.   Error help link:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026
>
> Feature:                       Обозреватель SQL   Status:
> Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Модуль записи SQL   Status:
> Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Обратная совместимость клиентских
> средств   Status:                        Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Пакет SDK клиентских средств
> Status:                        Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Соединение с клиентскими средствами
> Status:                        Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Пакет SDK средств связи клиента SQL
> Status:                        Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Средства связи клиента SQL   Status:
> Пройдено
>
> Feature:                       Файлы поддержки программы установки
> Status:                        Пройдено
>
> Rules with failures or warnings:
>
> Global rules: Предупреждение IsFirewallEnabled
> Брандмауэр Windows включен. Чтобы обеспечить удаленный доступ,
> убедитесь, что открыты соответствующие порты. Сведения о портах,
> которые необходимо открыть для каждого из компонентов, см. в
> документации по правилам на странице
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2094702.
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
> Server\150\Setup
> Bootstrap\Log\20220112_200922\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Что пробовал:

- Включил службу "Установщик модулей Windows" и "Центр обновления Windows".
- [Этот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hekb99JzVkk) метод (установка учетной записи запуска службы SQL Server Database Engine на NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE)
- Так же пробовал ставить NT Authority\System

По факту всегда один результат:
[image: Завершено с ошибками]

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Вопрос Вы оформили просто идеально! Я, правда, не могу Вам помочь, но я много раз проделывал все эти установки и всё было ОК. вариантов я вижу два: 1) попробовать на десятой, а не 11 винде. просто посмотреть, будет ли установка без проблем. 2) установить в wsl2 MS SQL при помощи докера, как я это описывал здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347126/

Comment: @S.H. я недавно поменял ноутбук, до этого осенью устанавливал на 11-ой винде и всё работало. Честно говоря с докером я ещё не сталкивался, если представить, что всё пройдёт ок, то есть ли какие-то нюансы такой установки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я всё-таки нашёл решение. Дело действительно в Windows 11 в совокупности с современными дисками, как я понял. Размер сектора диска больше 4КБ (максимально поддерживаемый SQL Server) приводит к ошибкам.
Более подробно о проблеме и варианты решения [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size#resolutions).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в Windows 11. В ее первоначальной версии никаких проблем с установкой SQL 2019 не было. Но в каком-то летнем обновлении указанная ошибка с ненайденным дескриптором и прилетела. Поэтому решение такое: ставить SQL 2019 до получения всех необходимых обновлений системы. Если обновления уже установлены, то надо их удалить или вообще вернуть компьютер в первоначальное состояние и после этого на чистую Windows 11 установить SQL 2019. После этого можно обновляться, SQL 2019 работает нормально.
Других способов устранить эту ошибку пока не найдено.
Понятно, что эта ситуация временная, Microsoft должны выпустить обновления или Windows 11 или SQL 2019, где эта ошибка установки SQL сервера будет исправлена.

Comment: Не нужно удалять обновления и тем более переустанавливать систему, если у вас та же проблема. Проблема в том, что сектор диска в win 11 больше, чем поддерживает sql server. Но это можно изменить. Выше я оставил ссылку на более подробную информацию и вариант решения непосредственно от Майков.